# RabbitMQ latency in publishing messages

Tags: rabbitmq, delay, message, latency, pika

We are working on a project that uses rabbitMQ as message brocker as backbone using pika. We publish a message at every 0.5 seconds using a publisher running in a computer on the same network. A consumer runs on another system in the same network to consume the message. Unfortunately, I face latency in publishing the messages to the MQ after running the publisher and subscriber continuously for over 10 minutes. Publishing a message to the MQ occasionally takes a couple of seconds (even 30 seconds a couple of times). I have isolated this issue using small scripts to publish and subscribe.
Observatons

1. This latency is not observed when the publisher and subscriber runs on the same system.
2. This latency is not observed even when channel.confirm_delivery() is not set.
3. This issue is observed irrespective of the specs of the system. We tried this on several systems including a HP OMEN with corei7 cpu.
4. The network connectivity is also good and we were able to reproduce this issue using different networks at different places.

**Publisher code:**

```
import pika
import json
import time



PUBLISH_FREQUENCY = 2.0
PUBLISH_TIMEOUT = 0.5 #Seconds


MQ_IP_ADDRESS = #MQ IP ADDRESS
EXCHANGE = "test3" 
EXCHANGE_TYPE = "topic"
ROUTING_KEY = "ag.ack"
QUEUE = ROUTING_KEY


feedback = {"task": {"start_time": 1655203648.916807, "id": 135, "end_time": None, "marker_scanned_a": None, "name_user": "Z_Z", "actual_duration": None, "status_work": "Progress", "message": None}, "consumer_identifier": "W1", "worker_availability": "In_progress", "worker_battery_parameter": {"battery_capacity": 1.0, "temp": 12.586999893188477}}
params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
    heartbeat=60, blocked_connection_timeout=60, host=MQ_IP_ADDRESS
)
print('Connecting to MQ at IP '+MQ_IP_ADDRESS +' '+ ROUTING_KEY)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)

channel = connection.channel()


# channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE)
channel.exchange_declare(
    exchange=EXCHANGE,
    exchange_type=EXCHANGE_TYPE
)
# channel.queue_bind(exchange=EXCHANGE, queue=QUEUE,routing_key=ROUTING_KEY)

channel.confirm_delivery()
print('Connected to MQ at IP '+MQ_IP_ADDRESS+' '+ ROUTING_KEY)
count = 0
while True:
    feedback['task']['id'] = count
    message = json.dumps(feedback)

    count = count + 1
    start_time = time.time()    
    a= channel.basic_publish(
            exchange=EXCHANGE,
            routing_key=ROUTING_KEY,
            body=message
        )
    
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    if end_time-start_time > PUBLISH_TIMEOUT:
        print('Time taken to send the message is '+str(duration)+'. For message number '+str(count) + ' . Resetting the count to zero.')
        count = 0
    time.sleep(1/PUBLISH_FREQUENCY)


channel.close()
```

**Consumer code**

```
import pika
import time
import json


MQ_IP_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
EXCHANGE = "test3" 
EXCHANGE_TYPE = "topic"
ROUTING_KEY = "ag.ack"
QUEUE = ROUTING_KEY


params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
    heartbeat=600, blocked_connection_timeout=300, host=MQ_IP_ADDRESS
)
try:
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
    print('connected')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    time.sleep(20)
    print("waiting to reconnect")
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
# connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=EXCHANGE, exchange_type=EXCHANGE_TYPE)

channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE, durable=False)
channel.queue_bind(exchange=EXCHANGE, queue=QUEUE,routing_key=ROUTING_KEY)
print(' Dummy AOS receiver...')
print('[*] Waiting for messages from Agent. To exit press CTRL+C')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):

    payload = body.decode()
    message = json.loads(payload)
    msg_counter = message["task"]["id"]
    time.sleep(0.5)

    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    
    print('received '+str(msg_counter))

channel.basic_consume(
    queue=QUEUE, on_message_callback=callback,)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you report an issue with *any* software, not just RabbitMQ, you *must* report the versions of the software you are using. In this case, I'm assuming that you are using the following versions, since they are the most recent:

- Erlang 25.0.2
- RabbitMQ 3.10.5
- Pika 1.2.1
- Python 3.10.5

Your Python code uses `time.sleep`, which blocks Pika's I/O loop. You should switch to using the [`connection.sleep`](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/e389d85ef566f49908d6d16aa0ed31b00eda3f82/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py#L835-L853) method instead.

You also set the heartbeat to 600 seconds, which is not necessary.

Finally, by using `BlockingConnection` and `confirm_delivery()`, your code is using **synchronous** publisher confirmations. Instead, you should be using `SelectConnection` and process confirmations asynchronously. You would keep a dict of outstanding confirmations and then mark those messages as confirmed when the confirmation callback is called. Note that RabbitMQ may confirm messages in batches.

Please see [this example](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/main/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.py).

This is an interesting enough situation that if you'd like further assistance, share your complete, runnable code on GitHub and post a message in the [Pika discussions](https://github.com/pika/pika/discussions) and we can continue there.